# Injection Script no Opencart 1.5.6

Tags: php, opencart

Estou a ter um problema recorrente de código injectado numa loja online minha.
Uso a versão do opencart 1.5.6.

Normalmente injectam código em vários ficheiros e depois mudam a extensão do model/tool/image.php para image.suspected

Sabem como resolver?

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa verificar as permissões da pasta, e rever todos plugin e módulos utilizado, sempre bom utilizar versão paga e atualizada.

Também é recomendado atualizar seu opencart.